# P'garim Meitim -- Dead Corpses

Tags: words

The root p-g-r is used 22 times in tanach (as per Even Shoshan), and the dictionary explains them all as corpse (a dead body).

In 2 of those cases, one in Yeshayahu and one in M'lachim II, the phrase used is "פְּגָרִ֥ים מֵתִֽים" dead corpses. I was under the impression that all corpses were dead.

The [Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.19.35?lang=bi&with=Ralbag&lang2=en) in M'lachim II 19:35 reads

> והנה פגרים מתים הם גופי' מתים כי הגוף החי יקרא גם כן פגר

that p'garim meitim are dead bodies because a live body is also called "p-g-r"

First, where does the Ralbag get this idea -- where is p-g-r used as a specifically live body (I haven't checked through all the instances, but the Even Shoshan seemed insistent that the definition is consistently corpse)? Next, if it does mean "live body" then wouldn't the word, in the other contexts, need the adjective "dead" appended to it also to distinguish?

Comment: Have you ever learned the concept of Yaacov Avinu didn’t die? Also, think about the blessing you make each morning which includes the same language.

Comment: The blessing is exactly why I started thinking about the choice of that word, then of that phrase, so I found its source in tanach.

Comment: The concept of life and death as conceived in Torah is more involved than what is commonly understood. If memory serves, you may find a relevant discussion of this in a collection of the teachings of the Vilna Gaon called Sefer Ohrot HaGra.

Comment: I assume the Ralbag's source is this possuk itself.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3261427?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) essay, the root "PGR" may rarely refer also to "heaps" of [things], so maybe here it means "dead heaps"?

Comment: @Harel13 but then verses like D"H 2, 20:24 would make a lot less sense (and I'm sure that other instances would be likewise confusing).

Comment: I don't see the problem..? I said that it may rarely (/sometimes) mean heaps, not in every instance...

Comment: @Harel13 but that takes me back to the problem -- how does one know when and why doesn't the Ralbag explain the word as heaps?

Comment: @rosends that the Ralbag was not aware of this possible understanding does not trouble me. With all due respect, meanings of certain words were lost and have been rediscovered in recent centuries. Take for example the word פים which was understood by commentators to refer to something with the mouth but as it turns out, is actually a type of tanachic weight. As to how one would know - well, there examples of other words that mean different things depending on the context. When one knows the ancient Hebrew well enough, one knows how to differentiate.

Comment: Understood but the Ralbag makes an assertion but provides no citation. The pasuk the article references is understood by the ralbag to be "heaps for A"Z and the bodies/corpses of the followers of A"Z" and rashi calls them idols. If the word meant stellae or installations at A"Z sanctuaries, then the use in p'garim meitim, and its use in Bereisheet 15:11 would be troubling.

Comment: @rosends If you look at the verb form as found in Jastrow, 2 of the meanings are "to break apart", which is what I was directing you to in Sefer Ohrot HaGra, and also "to relax" or "to be idle". That 2nd meaning connects to the Yaacov Avinu didn't die concept mention in Shas. That Yaacov was simply laying idle and not moving.